# Google youtube Api error code 403

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-data-api

I am trying to implement google login for youtube channels. It is OK in queries like `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=123&key=AIzaSyCe-ZbUrOz1qLCyGbZVzRzB-wOvQfleeaE`.

But this URL gives an 403 error:

> `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&mine=true&access_token=".$client->getAccessToken())`

Comment: is _$client_ an object instantiated from the Google API php library (e.g. [Google_Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client))? Can you use the URL that works and replace the key with the value of _$client->getAccessToken()_?

Comment: [Error 403](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain) means your access is forbidden. I would suggest that you look into [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']); maybe the line you're looking for to get the access token.

Comment: Hi there; I took the liberty of editing your question to make the wording and the code more readable. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your questions to make them as good as possible; so if there is anything else you can tell us, please include the extra information in your question.